# Error report - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (igmr.FCS_FK1) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
INSERT INTO igmr.FCS
( 
  UNIT, 
    GROUP,
    LOC ,
    startdate ,
    DUR,
    type,
    FCSTID,
    QTY,
    DEL,
    NQTY,
    MAID ,
    code
    sour
    ty
    om
    ctry
    )

select 
    UNIT, 
    GROUP,
    LOC ,
    startdate ,
    DUR,
    type,
    FCSTID,
    QTY,
    DEL,
    NQTY,
    MAID ,
    code
    sour
    ty
    om
    ctry
    
    
from igmr.FOR;
```

Primary keys for table need to insert igmr.FCS are
UNIT,
GROUP,
LOC ,
startdate ,
DUR,
type,
FCSTID

Foreign keys are :-

UNIT,
GROUP,
LOC ,
DEL

Comment: You're trying to insert a value into igmr.FCS that doesn't satisfy the foreign key. I.e. that value should already exists in the referenced table.

Comment: Why do you [delete and ask the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76060907/error-report-ora-02291-integrity-constraint-igmr-fcst-pk-violated-parent?noredirect=1#comment134143142_76060907)? Please clarify what is not clear in the error message and what did you try so far.

Comment: I inserted the calculation in one table and now getting same error thats y

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key you named `FK1` is violated; we don't know which one because you didn't reveal that information.

As you're inserting values into `FCS` table (whose foreign key constraint was violated) from `FOR` table, it means that (at least one) value in foreign key columns you specified (`unit`, `group`, `loc`, `del`) doesn't exist in `master_table.column` which is referenced by that foreign key.

How to find such values? For example, you could

```
select unit from master_table
minus
select unit from for;
```

Make sure that `for` table contains only valid values (or don't insert then if they are invalid, or remove foreign key constraint).